# unexpected SPARQL playground answer (VALUES and OPTIONAL)

Tags: sparql

Consider the following SPARQL query:

```
select * where
{
  values ?x { 1 2 3 } .
  optional { values (?x ?xp) { (2 2) (3 3) (4 4) } }
}
```

I would think it returns the following:

```
?x ?xp
------
1  NULL
2  2
3  3
```

However, the "SPARQL playground" http://sparql-playground.isb-sib.ch/ returns the following:

```
?x ?xp
------
2  2
3  3
4  4
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: http://dbpedia.org/sparql does return the result I expected. So this may be a bug in the SPARQL engine used by the playground. I will contact them.

Comment: Did you get any response?

Comment: Yes, it was a bug. They have now updated their engine.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it was a but due to the Sesame engine.
The current engine, Sesame 2.8.6 fixed the problem.